# phalcon - 500 error on model::find();?

Tags: phalcon

error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

This is what is causing the error:

```
//$that["model"] contains: 'Users'
$user = $that["model"]::findFirst("username='$username' AND password='$password'");
```

When I remove that line, the error dissapears.

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$config->database` data is not correct, that is why.